# Read TCP Options Fields

Tags: c, linux, networking, tcp

I'm linking linux/tcp.h and I'm trying to read the TCP options, I can't seem to find how to do so. I've read a bit online and according to some online sources I have to iterate all of the "remaining packet" until I hit the option(s) I want? (Right now I'm going to try and focus on the "MSS" option). Can anyone provide me with a code example of it?

```
struct iphdr *iph = ((struct iphdr *) full_packet);
    fprintf(stdout, "IP{v=%u; ihl=%u; tos=%u; tot_len=%u; id=%u; ttl=%u; protocol=%u; "
        ,iph->version, iph->ihl*4, iph->tos, ntohs(iph->tot_len), ntohs(iph->id), iph->ttl, iph->protocol);

    if (iph->protocol == 6){

        struct tcphdr *tcp = ((struct tcphdr *) (full_packet + (iph->ihl << 2)));
        fprintf(stdout, "TCP{sport=%u; dport=%u; seq=%u; ack_seq=%u; flags=u%ua%up%ur%us%uf%u; window=%u; urg=%u}\n",
            ntohs(tcp->source), ntohs(tcp->dest), ntohl(tcp->seq), ntohl(tcp->ack_seq)
            ,tcp->urg, tcp->ack, tcp->psh, tcp->rst, tcp->syn, tcp->fin, ntohs(tcp->window), tcp->urg_ptr);\
    }
```

Is what I have so far in terms of reading/parsing the IP/TCP data

Thanks!

Bump...any help is appreciated!

Progress update (thanks to @WillisBlackburn) :

```
struct iphdr *iph = ((struct iphdr *) full_packet);

fprintf(stdout, "IP{v=%u; ihl=%u; tos=%u; tot_len=%u; id=%u; ttl=%u; protocol=%u; "
    ,iph->version, iph->ihl*4, iph->tos, ntohs(iph->tot_len), ntohs(iph->id), iph->ttl, iph->protocol);

if (iph->protocol == 6){

    struct tcphdr *tcp = ((struct tcphdr *) (full_packet + (iph->ihl << 2)));

    uint8_t *p = (uint8_t *)tcp + 20;
    uint8_t *end = (uint8_t *)tcp + tcp->doff * 4;
    uint16_t mss = 0; 
    printf("\nThe offset is %d\n", tcp->doff);
    printf("Let's check what's at location p: %u is supposed to be less than %d\n",(*(uint8_t *)tcp + 20), (uint8_t)end);
    while (p < end) {
        uint8_t kind = *p++;
        if (kind == 0) {
            printf("The kind is 0?\n");
            break;
        }
        if (kind == 1) {
            // No-op option with no length.
            continue;
        }
        uint8_t size = *p++;
        if (kind == 2) {
            mss = ntohs(*(uint16_t *)p);
            printf("The MSS value is: %d\n", mss);
        }
        p += (size - 2);
    }

    fprintf(stdout, "TCP{sport=%u; dport=%u; seq=%u; ack_seq=%u; flags=u%ua%up%ur%us%uf%u; window=%u; urg=%u}\n",
        ntohs(tcp->source), ntohs(tcp->dest), ntohl(tcp->seq), ntohl(tcp->ack_seq)
        ,tcp->urg, tcp->ack, tcp->psh, tcp->rst, tcp->syn, tcp->fin, ntohs(tcp->window), tcp->urg_ptr);

}
```

**More progress:**

Found some cool implementations of reading TCP options; however, I'm not quite sure in the implementation of it in my code. Any help from people?  Here's what I found:

https://github.com/multipath-tcp/mptcp/blob/214e17c446d98e238c3bc8a3177990eae6a7059b/net/ipv4/tcp_input.c#L3674-L3789

https://github.com/multipath-tcp/mptcp/blob/02bc9ec8da25e0e71f9d1fec02be4632a0846092/include/net/tcp.h#L170-L210

It seems a bit more complex than WillisBlackburn's and would possibly take care of the issue with the kind being too large? (200+ with some packets rather than the "2" that we're expecting with a MSS (+other options that are in the TCP packet).

Help is appreciated!!!

I'll be in chat.freenode.net (niven.freenode.net) in channel #adamc if you wanna talk about it!

**Latest Update:**

So, I based it off of the MTCP but here is the code: (added user tests):

```
const unsigned char *ptr;
const struct tcphdr *th = ((struct tcphdr *) (full_packet + (iph->ihl << 2)));
int length = (th->doff * 4) - sizeof(struct tcphdr);

ptr = (const unsigned char *)(th + 1);

while(length > 0){
  printf("Got in the while loop\n");
  int opcode = *ptr++;
  int opsize;

  switch(opcode) {
    case 0:
      printf("Got the initial val (EOL)\n");
      return;
    case 1:
      printf("Got the NOP val as well!\n");
      length--;
      continue;
    default:
      printf("Entered default.\n");
      opsize = *ptr++;
      printf("Does stuff after setting the OPSize.\n");
      if(opsize < 2) {
        printf("OPSize = %d < 2;Length = %d\n", opsize, length);
        return;
      }
      if(opsize > length) {
        printf("OPSize = %d > Length = %d\n", opsize, length);
        return;
      }
      switch(opcode) {
        printf("Switching the OPCode\n");
        case 2: //TCP MSS
          if(opsize == 4 && th->syn) {
            printf("MSS: %d\n", ptr);
          }
        case 3: //TCP Window
          if(opsize==3 && th->syn) {
            uint8_t wscale = *(uint8_t *)ptr;
            if(wscale>14) {
              printf("Illgal wscale value: %d\n", wscale);
            }
            printf("WSCALE: %d\n", *(uint8_t*)ptr);
          }
          break;
        case 8: //Timestamp
          if(opsize==10) {
            printf("Timestamp is present!!!\n");
          }
          break;
        case 4: //TCP SACK
          if((opsize >= (2+8)) && !((opsize-2)%8)) {
            printf("SACK val: %d\n", ((ptr-2)- (unsigned char *)th));
          }

        default:
          printf("Entered default of switching OPCode\n");
          return;
      }
      ptr += opsize-2;
      length -= opsize;
  }
}
```

so now I'm on the issue of:
When I make a request, it gives me the following:

```
IP{v=4; ihl=20; tos=0; tot_len=64; id=48952; ttl=61; protocol=6; Got in the while loop
Entered default.
Does stuff after setting the OPSize.
OPSize = 127 > Length = 12
```

So basically, it entered the while loop, entered the default (switching between the opsizes) and everything; however, the OPSize is 127 (greater than length) so I believe I'm doing something wrong in getting the sizes. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Is it user-space program? Why do you need options? Where did you get the packet? According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#TCP_segment_structure Options are just after fixed fields of tcp header, but they have no fixed structure. Do check "Data offset" field `doff` field of [struct tcphdr](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/uapi/linux/tcp.h?v=4.10#L24), increment pointer to packet and parse them (or ask to parse something which gives you the `full_packet`). Example: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/netfilter/xt_tcpmss.c?v=4.10#L47 - TCPOPT_MSS

Comment: @osgx Yes it's a user-space program. I'm reading the options in a firewall and I'm getting the packet from netfilter through their queuing system. I'm still kinda confused by that example..do you have any other examples that are easier to read or any that work specifically with the one above?

Comment: I have no other example and I found the only confusing point in this one - pointer increment with `op = skb_header_pointer(skb, par->thoff + sizeof(*th), optlen, _opt);` - replace it with `const u_int8_t *op = ((u_int8_t *) full_packet ) + tcphdr.doff*4 - sizeof(struct tcphdr)`. Macro are defined in include/net/tcp.h - http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/net/tcp.h#L175  TCPOPT_MSS              2    TCPOLEN_MSS            4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two possible answers: how to get the MSS (maximum segment size) of a TCP connection and how to parse the TCP header.

If all you want to know is what the MSS of the connection is, then you can use the `getsockopt` function on an open socket. Pass it the file descriptor, IPPROTO_TCP as the level, TCP_INFO as the option, the address of a `struct tcp_info` (from tcp.h) that will hold the output, and `sizeof (struct tcp_info)`. The kernel will fill in the fields of `struct tcp_info` and you can get the MSS from `tcpi_snd_mss` or `tcpi_rcv_mss`.

If you actually want to parse the TCP header itself, then you have to understand the layout of the header. The `struct tcphdr` you're using doesn't include the options, which come after the fields in `struct tcphdr`. Each option field is a single byte identifying the option kind, optionally followed by a second byte specifying the size of the option (including the kind and size bytes), followed by additional data.

There may not be any options at all. You have to start by looking at the data offset field of the TCP header (`doff`). It's in 32-bit words. The size of the standard header, defined by `struct tcphdr`, is 20 bytes, so options can only be present if `doff` is greater than 5 (times 4 bytes = 20 bytes).

Assuming there are options, you can read them like this. Note that option kind for MSS is 2 and that option kind 0 signifies the end of the options list, but only if the end of the options list doesn't already coincide with the start of the data as per `doff`. Option kinds 0 and 1 (no-op) are a single byte. The other option kinds have a size byte that follows the kind and specifies the size of the options field (including the kind and size fields).

```
uint8_t *p = (uint8_t *)tcp + 20; // or sizeof (struct tcphdr)
uint8_t *end = (uint8_t *)tcp + tcp->doff * 4;
uint16_t mss = 0; 
while (p < end) {
    uint8_t kind = *p++;
    if (kind == 0) {
        break;
    }
    if (kind == 1) {
        // No-op option with no length.
        continue;
    }
    uint8_t size = *p++;
    if (kind == 2) {
        mss = ntohs(*(uint16_t *)p);
    }
    p += (size - 2);
}
```

I haven't tested this, but it should be pretty close.

I can't find any documentation that confirms that only TCP options kinds 0 and 1 do not include a size byte. The specification for TCP is [RFC 793](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793), which is (as of this writing) 35 years old and only mentions option kinds 0, 1, and 2. It suggests that whether or not the size byte is present depends on the option kind. But that means that in order to parse the headers correctly, your program has to be aware of [all the possible options it might encounter](http://www.iana.org/assignments/tcp-parameters/tcp-parameters.xhtml). For example, if the options segment of the header contained the bytes 16, 2, 4, 1, and 0, does that mean an option of kind 16, followed by a size byte of 2, followed by option kind 4 (since a size of 2 would mean the option consisted solely of the kind and size)? Or does it mean an option of kind 16 with no size byte, followed by an option of kind 2 (MSS), followed by a size byte of 4? You can't know unless you know whether option type 16, "Skeeter," should be followed by a size byte or not.

Comment: Can you have less magic constants in your code by using some standard linux `tcp.h` header?

Comment: Any suggestions? I looked in tcp.h but there really wasn't much in there about options at all.

Comment: Is the th_off the same as the doff option? It said that it didn't have th_off but I'm assuming it's the same?

Comment: Yes--I was looking at the BSD version of the struct in netinet/tcp.h.

Comment: Updated to use doff.

Comment: So, I tried it and it didn't seem to work. I added verbosity to it so I could make sure it's working and I didn't receive any value when I tried to print mss ( printf("The MSS value is: %d\n", mss); ), added a usertest in the check if kind is 0 as well and it didn't break there. Not quite sure what's up. Let me know if you want me to post the code with the user tests here.

Comment: Well, what's `tcp->doff`, and what's `*((uint8_t *)tcp + 20)`?

Comment: https://hastebin.com/raw/eziyanufih if its hard to read


It says the offset(tcp->doff) is 12. Not sure how to check what's at a position (tried to guess it out and print p (which is already defined as tcp+20) and it gave a question park):

`

        uint8_t *p = (uint8_t *)tcp + 20; // or sizeof (struct tcphdr)
        uint8_t *end = (uint8_t *)tcp + tcp->doff * 4;
        uint16_t mss = 0; 
        printf("\nThe offset is %d\n", tcp->doff);
        printf("Let's check what's at location %s\n", p);
` 

Gave response:

_
The offset is 12
Let's check what's at location ?
_

Comment: Change the last line to: `printf("Let's check what's at location p: %u\n",(unsigned int)*p);`

Comment: The offset is 3
Let's check what's at location p: 57

Comment: Something else is wrong. You should never see a value for doff that is less than 5 since the minimum size of a TCP header is 20 bytes (5 32-bit words).

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought, so I switched it to sizeof instead of the hard coded tcp+20 like the following https://hastebin.com/egahakupom.c and got:
The offset is 11
Let's check what's at location p: 20
Segmentation fault

Comment: Are you looking at the same packet every time? Could you post a hex dump of it?

Comment: For this test purpose yeah it's the same packet each time (or rather it should be, yes.) 
https://hastebin.com/raw/efopavoqaz

Comment: The doff field is the value `b` at offset 0x20, so it's definitely 11 as you say. That means the TCP header is 44 bytes long. You can see the MSS option: it's the sequence `0204 0546` at offset 0x28. By the way your tool shows you exactly what options are present and the order in which they appear: `[mss 1350,nop,wscale 5,nop,nop,TS val 1783056299 ecr 0,sackOK,eol]`. The `0204 0546` sequence is `mss 1350` and is immediately followed by `01` which your tool correctly identifies as nop, etc. So there are quite a few options and the doff of 11 seems correct.

Comment: Yeah the math of how large everything is seems to be fine, any idea what to do next @WillisBlackburn ? There is a seg. fault when I changed it to do the sizeof tcphdr (https://hastebin.com/raw/qafucoyadi) so maybe that's it?

Comment: Well `uint8_t *p = sizeof(struct tcphdr)` isn't going to work. You're setting the pointer to the constant 20--in other words it now points to memory location 20. You have to cast `tcp` to `uint8_t` and then add 20 to it. `sizeof (struct tcphdr)` has to be 20 (it's in the RFC) so there's no harm in just using 20.

Comment: Okay so now that it's set to 20 I think I found the issue, but I'm not sure why it is/how to fix it. Essentially, the kind is 236 (in this example). :

Let's check what's at location p: 20 is supposed to be less than 128
The Kind is: 236

I did the kind after all of the if statements to check if it actually was less than end. https://hastebin.com/raw/cagorulode
Maybe this is due to the multiple TCP options?

Comment: If you'll post your compete source and the full output then I can probably figure out what's happening.

Comment: pluse uno for tech support! Good luck to all.

Comment: Did you have any luck @WillisBlackburn ?

Comment: What does it output on your machine?

Comment: @WillisBlackburn I think it'll be easier to explain it without having to post a comment each time, any preferred IRC or anything? I would use the chat but I can't (rank or whatever)

Comment: For clarification for anyone else trying to help:
There isn't any specific output, it grabs the traffic from IPTables queues and then parses the traffic from that and gives it a verdict.

Comment: Adam, your program contains a lot of print statements. I'm just asking you to post what the program outputs when you run it.

Comment: Oh sorry, it gives "Please give us a queue number to bind to!" And then you input the queue number (0/1/2, etc) and then the function where it calls is "nfqueue". I'm on my phone right now so sorry for any mistakes in that. (Or did you mean the exact output with all of the kinds, etc.? I updated the post yesterday with the output of that)

Comment: Is that what you were asking or am I way off @WillisBlackburn ?

Comment: I was looking for the complete output of the program hifuvagoba.c  you posted earlier.

Comment: Something strange is going on with your program because your logic looks correct yet the program is producing nonsensical results. I suggest you write a very simple program that simply declares an array with the packet data (based on your hex dump it would look like `unsigned char[] packet = { 0x45, 0x00, 0x00, 0x40, 0x63, 0x7b, ... }`) and then call your parse routine with that and see if you can read the data. If that works then keep adding functionality back until you figure out what's going wrong. If it doesn't work then post the entire program and I'll try to run it myself.

Comment: @WillisBlackburn so I did one better (or at least one better in my opinion), I echo'd out the hex of the packet that I received and checked it against a TCPDump that is running on the same packet. They got the same hexs to an extent (or as far as I can tell it's the same):

TCPDump: https://i.dosattack.net/stpP.png
Printed hex: https://i.dosattack.net/DILg.png

Comment: The only changes I made from your code, apart from copying it into this program and removing unnecessary lines, was to fix two bugs in the line that prints "Let's check what's at location p."

Comment: Output of the program I just posted: https://hastebin.com/raw/amaqesesem

Comment: @WillisBlackburn so I did just notice something: 
the output of the program I just made (prints the hex: https://hastebin.com/raw/kepehapogo)
The hex it prints ends short (or I believe it does), maybe that's the reason? For example:

Hex the program prints: 45000040dcf940003d0673ea17ee82aa2d22251a

Hex TCPump prints:
https://hastebin.com/raw/vayuxagobo

Them in the same format:
https://hastebin.com/raw/usepodipin

Thoughts?

Comment: @WillisBlackburn Found the bug! The program was limiting the reading size, changed the limit to the highest (0xffff) and it works now! Thanks for dealing with this all, you've been a huge help! You're the best!

Comment: You know, it did occur to me early on that your packet capture program might be truncating the packets, which they often do in order to avoid capturing tons of data. But since something in your program was printing out all the options ("mss 1350,nop,wscale 5,nop,nop,TS val 1783056299 ecr 0,sackOK,eol") I thought it must have the whole header. Maybe it only gave you access to part of it?

Comment: Since my logic works could you make the answer correct? :-)

Comment: @WillisBlackburn oh I did a while ago, it says "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.".

Comment: I mean, click the checkbox underneath the feedback arrows.